# Active Directory on-prem Manager

Tags: active-directory

I need to implement an Active Directory(on-prem) manager in which user can do all tasks like add user, delete user, assign license and assign groups etc. User has username, password and domain controller name, so he just login to my app and manage everything. Actually arranging client properties physically is to a great wastage of time and particularly one should have intense knowledge of native tools and PowerShell.

So i am new to these technologies, can anyone please let me know the whole idea behind this. Already services are up like (https://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/active-directory-management.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you want to stay on-premises? If you are willing to sync to the cloud Azure AD is great for user self-management. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-self-service-management

Quest also has an on-premises software with something similar to what you are looking for. https://www.quest.com/products/active-administrator/

Comment: thanks.. Yea you are right just like Quest i want to build but i can not get direction? How they are doing? New on these things.